# What is the proper/canonical way to serve JSON data with Django?

Tags: django, json, django-templates, django-views

I would like to deliver JSON responses with Django to my jQuery based clients.

I could just design a template that instead of markup delivers JSON, but there must be a way to do this easier.

What is the common practice in the Django community?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using python 2.6 or higher:

```
import json
```

Else:

```
import simplejson as json
```

Then you can use this in your view code:

```
foo = {'bar': ['baz', 'etc']}
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(foo), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: Don't use simplejson unless you are using python 2.5 or lower; it is now built in to the python standard library.  Django ships with built-in serializers that make use of either simplejson or json, depending on your version of python.

Comment: @GDorn: Thanks, totally forgot that it's been added to the standard library, I'm so engrained in the habit of importing it via simplejson. Updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

["Serializing Django objects"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serializing-django-objects)

[`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html)